# Array Picture cycle timer

Tags: c#, arrays, image, timer, picturebox

Hi I have a slight problem I created a timer to display 6 pictures it cycles though the picture in picturebox 1 and 2 but for some reason it doesnt display any picture just an x mark.
I got the picture format right but I am not sure what the problem is can anyone help?

```
    string[] picture = {
                       @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die1.jpg",
                       @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die2.jpg",
                         @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die3.jpg",
                           @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die4.jpg",
                             @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die5.jpg",
                                @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die6.jpg"};
    int index = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.ImageLocation = string.Format(@"ImageResource\Die_Images\{0}.jpg", index);
        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        index++;
        if (index >= picture.Length)
            index = 0;
        else
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = string.Format(@"ImageResource\Die_Images\{0}.jpg", index);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should this

```
pictureBox2.ImageLocation = string.Format(@"ImageResource\Die_Images\{0}.jpg", index);
```

be this?

```
pictureBox2.ImageLocation = string.Format(@"ImageResource\Die_Images\die{0}.jpg", index);
```

Comment: oh that works you know  a way where I can make picturebox2 start one the second picture ?

Answer (score 1):

you need `"die"+index`

```
 string.Format(@"ImageResource\Die_Images\{0}.jpg", "die"+index);
                                                      ^^^
```

Your image names are `die1.jpg`,`die2.jpg`... but you are trying to display `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` and so on... Also you should start your index from `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: Anyway for me to give picturebox2 have a head start?